# pd.to_datetime inserting random dates and not comparing against todays date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a birth_date column.

df

```
birth_date:
1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

The source I am reading the data from is another dataframe and the `birth_date` datatype is object.

When I go to convert the column to date type I get random dates put in. Code:

```
df['birth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birth_date'], errors='coerce')
```

The exact dates that are getting are:

```
birth_date
0   1990-06-11
1   2017-12-01
```

I have no idea why.

All I want to do is take todays code and see if it is someones birthday and assign an ID. Code so far to do that, it worked, but not sure what is causing it to fail:

```
df['birth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['birth_date'],errors = 'coerce')

#from datetime import date
#today = str(date.today()) experimenting with this no luck
today = pd.to_datetime('today')


SegmentID = np.select( 
    [
 df.birth_date.eq(today) & df['type'].eq('m'),


    ],
    [1],
    default=np.nan
)

df = df.assign(SegmentID=SegmentID).dropna(subset=['SegmentID'])
```